# Is this furniture question on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

My concern is that since it has nothing to do with building or modifying furniture it's a little suspect.  However,  I think this community could answer it without stretching much.

"How do you calculate load capacity for a large piece of furniture, like an entertainment center or china cabinet?"

Given a particular material and structure, joints, etc how does one calculate what it can hold safely?

UPDATE:  I really am interested in learning more about this, so I asked the [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/how-can-i-estimate-the-load-capacity-of-a-set-of-shelves) to match an actual project I'm planning for so it hopefully fits the spirit of the site.  I built a "shelving unit" out of 2x10s while in a dorm - would have been nice to know that was a massive overkill back then :)  And if it should be closed, that's fine too.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: @ChrisF Well if the second one is on-topic but the first is not, then it seems like you could get the information by rephrasing the question.

Comment: @ChrisF - I haven't asked the question yet, I was checking to see it it was strictly out of bounds.

Comment: Sounds like a physics/engineering question to me, though it may be off topic on physics.SE and there is no engineering.SE.  It's likely @[Doresoom](http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/20/doresoom) could answer it, but it would have to be a fairly detailed question for anybody to really take a stab at it.

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inclined to say no, unless you're *building* something with the material. That would clearly make it a "DIY" question.

It's not entirely off-topic, though, because I could see questions about load bearing properties of home structures being acceptable. Maybe give it a shot and see what happens?