# Is mould removal from furnishings on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to raise a question about how best to remove mould from this armchair. The chair has been placed for several months in an area where we suspect there is damp.

[image]

Is this on-topic for Home Improvement Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject of furniture has come up several times on diy.meta, and it's generally been the consensus that unless the question involves woodworking it's off topic.

The most relevant may be [Furniture repair off topic?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/753/furniture-repair-off-topic). See also [Is this furniture question on topic?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394/is-this-furniture-question-on-topic) and [Is upholstery on topic?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/is-upholstery-on-topic).

Comment: And the woodworking questions, while on-topic, may get better responses over at [woodworking.se].